# How to set related parentheses with same color but different with other parentheses in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to use notepad++.

example:

```
  (A(B))
```

explain detailed:

```
  (  -> first parenthesis start, example with red(random select)
  A 
  (  -> second parenthesis start, example with blue(random select)
  B
  )  -> second parenthesis end, example with blue(same as the second parenthesis color)
  )  -> first parenthesis end, example with red(same as the first parenthesis color)
```

How to do that to make easy to match parentheses?

Thank you~

Comment: Do you mean that they are coloured at all times, or only when the cursor is on them (as in Notepad++ 5.8.6)?

Comment: I want it show all times. Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is nothing like colored parenthesis pairs present in Notepad++ or in any plugins I know. You can leave a **feature request** following the link with the same name on [Notepad++ website](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/).